# 22 students were in the class. 16 took math, 14 took English and 18 took history.

Tags: arithmetic

22 students were in the class. 16  took math, 14 took English and 18 took history. At maximum how many took math, English, and history? All took at least one subject.

I was thinking to solve it with this equation as sets.n(A ∪ B ∪ C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) - n(A ∩ B) - n(B ∩ C) - n(C ∩ A) + n(A ∩ B ∩ C) trying to find n(A ∩ B ∩ C). But unfortunately there is no information regarding n(A ∩ B) , n(B ∩ C) , n(C ∩ A). So I am confused which approach should I take to solve it

Comment: I was thinking to solve it with this equation as sets.n(A ∪ B ∪ C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) - n(A ∩ B) - n(B ∩ C) - n(C ∩ A) + n(A ∩ B ∩ C) trying to find n(A ∩ B ∩ C). But unfortunately there is no information regarding n(A ∩ B) , n(B ∩ C) , n(C ∩ A). So I am confused which approach should I take to solve it ?

Comment: @JoshuaWang can you please clarify what do you mean by a range of numbers?

Comment: @JoshuaWang The question says *at most* how many, so there should be sufficient information.

Comment: @JoshuaWang So you think it is not solvable with the amount of information given? So maybe a trick question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were asked exactly how many students took all three subjects, you would need more information than what is given, but the question asks for the maximum number of students who took all three subjects.

There can't be more than $14$, since only $14$ took English.  Can there be as many as $14$?  That would leave $2$ who took math, but not history, and $4$ who took history, but not math, for a total of $$14+2+4=20$$ but there are $22$ students.  Therefore, fewer than $14$ took all three subjects.

The point is that if $14$ students took all three courses, and the other data are as given in the problem, then there are $20$ students in all, but we are told in the problem that there are $22$ students.  Therefore, it is not the case that $14$ students took all three subjects.

Can you extend this line of reasoning to answer the question?

Comment: The question is asking for the maximum number

Comment: @dawid09239y2 Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @JoshuaWang  can you please elaborate on the logic and the relationship you are trying to make with the total number 22 and the number 20? I am just having confusion about why you mentioned'' but there are 22 students" . the number 20 is it the number of possible students who took all three?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = $ then number of students who took all three.

Let $ME =$ then number of students who took english and math only.

Let $MH= $ then number of students who took math and history only.

Let $HE= $ then number of students who took history and english only.

Then $14-ME-HE - X=$ then number of students who only took english.

$16-ME - MH-X=$ the number of students who only took math.

$18-MH - HE - X= $ then number of students who only took history.

$X + ME + MH + HE + (14-ME-HE - X) + (16-ME-MH-X) + (18-MH-HE -X) = 22$

$-2X-ME-MH-HE + 48 =22$

$26 -ME -MH -HE = 2X$

we want to maximize $X$ so we can do that by minimizing $ME,MH,HE$.

Can they all be $0$?  That would mean $13$ students took all three.  Then of the $14$ students who took english $14-13=1$ of them didn't take all three. That person couldn't take two classes so that person just took english. So $1$ person took only English.

Of the $16$ who took math, $16-13=3$ of then didn't take all three so $3$ took just math. And of the $18$ who took history $18 -13= 5$ took just history.

And that means $1+3+5=9$ people took just one class, $0$ people took two, and $13$ took all three and $13 + 0 + 9 =22$ so... that's possible.

The maximum number that took all three is $13$.